# How can i insert data in two different tables in mysql database at the same time?

Tags: php, mysql, session

I want to insert data into two different tables in mysql database at the same time but my data is only inserted into the user_signup table and not into the other table. This is my codes:

```
<?php
//If user is a ministry head
if($access_level == 'ministry_head')
{
    $sql="INSERT INTO ministry_head (eemail,mobile_number,fname,mname,lname,access_level,region_name,district_name,ssn,district_pass,pass_con) VALUES ('$eemail','$mobile_number','$fname','$mname','$lname','$access_level','$region_name','$district_name','$ssn','$district_pass','$pass_con')";
    $sql="INSERT INTO user_signup (eemail,mobile_number,fname,mname,lname,access_level,region_name,district_name,ssn,district_pass,pass_con) VALUES ('$eemail','$mobile_number','$fname','$mname','$lname','$access_level','$region_name','$district_name','$ssn','$district_pass','$pass_con')";
    $_SESSION['eemail'] = $eemail;
    header('Location: ministry_head_page.php');             
}           
//If user is a regional head            
else if($access_level == 'regional_head')
{
    $sql="INSERT INTO regional_head (eemail,mobile_number,fname,mname,lname,access_level,region_name,district_name,ssn,district_pass,pass_con) VALUES ('$eemail','$mobile_number','$fname','$mname','$lname','$access_level','$region_name','$district_name','$ssn','$district_pass','$pass_con')";
    $sql="INSERT INTO user_signup (eemail,mobile_number,fname,mname,lname,access_level,region_name,district_name,ssn,district_pass,pass_con) VALUES ('$eemail','$mobile_number','$fname','$mname','$lname','$access_level','$region_name','$district_name','$ssn','$district_pass','$pass_con')";
    $_SESSION['eemail'] = $eemail;
    header('Location: regional_head_page.php');             
}           
//if user is general user 
else if($access_level == 'general_user')
{
    $sql="INSERT INTO general_user (eemail,mobile_number,fname,mname,lname,access_level,region_name,district_name,ssn,district_pass,pass_con) VALUES ('$eemail','$mobile_number','$fname','$mname','$lname','$access_level','$region_name','$district_name','$ssn','$district_pass','$pass_con')";
    $sql="INSERT INTO user_signup (eemail,mobile_number,fname,mname,lname,access_level,region_name,district_name,ssn,district_pass,pass_con) VALUES ('$eemail','$mobile_number','$fname','$mname','$lname','$access_level','$region_name','$district_name','$ssn','$district_pass','$pass_con')";
    $_SESSION['eemail'] = $eemail;
     header('Location: general_user_page.php');     
}       
//if user is car company    
else if ($access_level == 'car_company')
{
    $sql="INSERT INTO car_company (eemail,mobile_number,fname,mname,lname,access_level,region_name,district_name,ssn,district_pass,pass_con) VALUES ('$eemail','$mobile_number','$fname','$mname','$lname','$access_level','$region_name','$district_name','$ssn','$district_pass','$pass_con')";
    $sql="INSERT INTO user_signup (eemail,mobile_number,fname,mname,lname,access_level,region_name,district_name,ssn,district_pass,pass_con) VALUES ('$eemail','$mobile_number','$fname','$mname','$lname','$access_level','$region_name','$district_name','$ssn','$district_pass','$pass_con')";
    $_SESSION['eemail'] = $eemail;  
    header('Location: car_company_page.php');   
}     
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{  
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "";
mysqli_clos
e($con); 
} 
?>
```

Comment: looking at **this** code, I guess you just use variables directly coming from user input. A security nightmare. Please read about *prepared statements* and use them (there are different ways to do this in PHP)

Comment: I am using variables that are inputted through a sign up form and want data inputted to be stored in different tables.

Comment: Ok, then I'll browse to your form and input `'; DROP TABLE ministry_head; `

Comment: BTW, your database scheme is flawed. Read about [Database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) .. you really shouldn't store the *same* data in *multiple* tables, use *foreign keys* instead.

Answer (score 2):

You assign two different strings to one variable:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO car_company ...";
$sql="INSERT INTO user_signup ...";
```

Second row overwrites the first one, hence it'll not execute. As a workaround you could do:

```
$sql1="INSERT INTO car_company ...";
$sql2="INSERT INTO user_signup ...";
```

followed by

```
mysqli_query($con,$sql1);
mysqli_query($con,$sql2);
```

with appropriate error checking and all.

Comment: The data is now inserted into the first table 'car_company' and not the second table 'user_signup'.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql="INSERT INTO ministry_head (eemail,mobile_number,fname,mname,lname,access_level,region_name,district_name,ssn,district_pass,pass_con) 
VALUES ('$eemail','$mobile_number','$fname','$mname','$lname','$access_level','$region_name','$district_name','$ssn','$district_pass','$pass_con')";
$sql .="INSERT INTO user_signup (eemail,mobile_number,fname,mname,lname,access_level,region_name,district_name,ssn,district_pass,pass_con) 
VALUES ('$eemail','$mobile_number','$fname','$mname','$lname','$access_level','$region_name','$district_name','$ssn','$district_pass','$pass_con')";
```

OR

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ministry_head (eemail,mobile_number,fname,mname,lname,access_level,region_name,district_name,ssn,district_pass,pass_con) 
VALUES ('$eemail','$mobile_number','$fname','$mname','$lname','$access_level','$region_name','$district_name','$ssn','$district_pass','$pass_con'); INSERT INTO user_signup (eemail,mobile_number,fname,mname,lname,access_level,region_name,district_name,ssn,district_pass,pass_con) 
VALUES ('$eemail','$mobile_number','$fname','$mname','$lname','$access_level','$region_name','$district_name','$ssn','$district_pass','$pass_con');";

multi_query($conn,$sql);
```

you need to use mysqli_* for this. assume $conn is your mysqli connection

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php